# How to change the color of the Mask View?

Tags: swift, mask

I am not sure if I understand the concept of Masking correctly but I am trying to recreate the Twitter logo expansion animation in their app:

[Twitter Logo expansion](http://78.media.tumblr.com/dc18fe45574cd486a2c7a2d5b72cc443/tumblr_inline_n6zoo1ve6a1qh9cw7.gif)

I have this code so far:

```
class LaunchScreenViewController: UIViewController {
    var mask: CALayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        setUpViewMask()
    }

    func setUpViewMask() {
        mask = CALayer()
        mask.contents = UIImage(named: "logo_mask")?.cgImage
        mask.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect
        mask!.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        mask!.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        mask!.position = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width/2, y: view.frame.size.height/2)
        view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 70/255, green: 154/255, blue: 233/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        view.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

[image]

How would I change the black background to be blue? I tried doing but it didn't seem to work:

```
view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 70/255, green: 154/255, blue: 233/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an intermediate layer where you apply mask. Set the background of your view to the desired background, and set background color of the intermediate layer to the color that you wish your mask to appear in. Something like this,

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 70/255, green: 154/255, blue: 233/255, alpha: 1)  // set background of the view portion that do not include mask


let parentLayer = CALayer()
parentLayer.frame = view.bounds
parentLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor // sets background of mask
view.layer.addSublayer(parentLayer) 

let mask = CALayer()
mask.contents = UIImage(named: "twitter.png")?.cgImage
mask.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect
mask.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
mask.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
mask.position = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width/2, y: view.frame.size.height/2)
parentLayer.mask = mask
```

Comment: So what I want to do is that my main background view should be white which has a UICollectionView in it. I want my parentLayer to be the blue color: `UIColor(red: 70/255, green: 154/255, blue: 233/255, alpha: 1)` so that it sits on top of my main view. But when I do `parentLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 70/255, green: 154/255, blue: 233/255, alpha: 1)` my main view is still visible even though I set my intermediate layer (parentLayer to blue). Can you help me with that?

Comment: Just add another CALayer between main view and parent layer again, now treat it as the background in above example.

Comment: Oh ok actually I think your example above did the trick can you explain to me how the mask works? I understand that you first set the main view's background color to blue. Then you set `parentLayer` background to white and added it on top of the main view so then it covered the main view blue background. But when I add the mask to the parentLayer how come the entire mask white background goes away and the blue background from the main view is visible? I am not understanding how this mask works.

Comment: See masking section in documentation for core graphics https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved by changing the background color of appDelegate's window...

```
let appDelegate  = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```